# If $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ show that $\tau_hf\to f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ as $h\to 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

$\tau_h:L^1\to L^1$ is defined by $\tau_hf(x)=f(x-h).$

It is easy to see that it holds if $f$ is continuous and has a compact support $K$.

Indeed, by the extremum value theorem, $|f(x-h)-f(x)|$ attains its maximum, say, $M_h$ in $K$, so $\int_K |f(x-h)-f(x)|\mathrm{d}x\leq M_h\int_K \mathrm{d}x$
and $M_h\to 0$.

Can I use this to prove the claim for the general case?
I would greatly appreciate any comment or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show that $f$ can be approximated by compactly supported functions and for this it suffices to show that if $E$ is Borel, and $\lambda (E)<\infty $ then $\chi_E$ can be approximated in $L^1$ norm by compactly supported functions. So, let $\epsilon>0$ and choose, by regularity of the Lebesgue measure, $K\subseteq E$ compact and $U\supseteq E$ open such that $\lambda (U\setminus K)<\epsilon$. Urysohn now gives an $f$ such that $\vert f\vert\leq 1; f(K)=1$ and $f(U^c)=0$ so that $f$ is compactly supported and now we have $\int \vert f-\chi_E \vert d\lambda <\lambda (U\setminus K)<\epsilon.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** use the fact that the set of continuous, compactly supported functions is dense in $L^1$.